# How to change boot priority/settings on Android phone(if possible)

Tags: arm

Does anybody know if Android phone's firmware has the option to boot from other media besides system on a chip? I assembled compatible ARM-machine code and placed it on an SD card and would like to know if it is possible to boot my small machine instructions this way.

Comment: Welcome to Programmers. Please take a moment to read the site's [FAQ] where you'll find good information about this site. This question would be better suited on SO as it deals with implementation details. Please don't re-ask it there as it can be migrated. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs  on SO. If it has you in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers.

Comment: Alright, so move it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've already voted to migrate it. If you want to speed the process up you can flag it for a moderator to review.

Comment: I highly doubt this is practical; the question seems fine here.

Comment: Programmers is for conceptual/design questions. If you think your question fits that category then I would suggest you edit it to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Booting from a different medium in fact has nothing to do with android, but rather the primary and possibly secondary boot-loaders.  Google doesn't mandate any particular booting arrangement, and its very much up to the phone vendor.

The TI OMAP family of SoCs has a ROM-based first stage boot-loader that can bring up the media card interface and boot from a FAT formatted media card - although the search order and availability of boot devices is controlled by pull-up resistors and your phone vendor might have disabled it.  It is likely other families of SoCs have similar arrangements.

Even once you've got your code to boot the is the question of what to use as IO? Or did you intend to back to a replacement kernel?

Comment: Google answer but Google provides fastboot so it is not entirely correct.